# Selection of UITableViewCell Changes when Scroll down in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am using a UITableView and what I am doing is I am changing the color of the cell when I tap on the cell using **didSelectRow** function of UITableView at *cellForRowAt*. The thing which is bothering me is when I scroll down or scroll up, those cells whom I changed the color before were changed to other cells. Here is my code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TasksTableViewCell") as! TasksTableViewCell

     cell.backView.backgroundColor = .white

  return cell
} 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  let cell = myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TasksTableViewCell

  cell.backView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "primaryViewColor")
}
```

Does anyone knows why this happens? Does anyone has a solution that when only those cells changes color whom I tap on, and when I scroll down or move up only those cells have the other color?

Comment: you scroll up and down and they changes back to white. right?

Comment: So as I understand you select a cell and after that other cells look like they are selected? If so I think this is happening because you change the background color of the cell and tableViews and collectionViews are reusing the cells, basically keeping the background you changed behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cellForRowAt will be called every time that cell is displayed.
you need selected list to save selected index.

```
var listSelected: [Int] = []
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TasksTableViewCell") as! TasksTableViewCell
    
    cell.backView.backgroundColor = listSelected.contains(indexPath.row) ? UIColor(named: "primaryViewColor") : .white
    
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if listSelected.contains(indexPath.row) {
        listSelected = listSelected.filter{$0 != indexPath.row}
    } else {
        listSelected.append(indexPath.row)
    }
    
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    
}
```

Comment: Exactly, this is right way to do...

Comment: I suggest using a `Set<Int>` or `Set<IndexPath>` instead of an array.

Comment: I suggest to add a `isSelected` property to the model.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered do you see the problem many times. Even if using and iVar  can solve the problem, You are mixing "Controller" logic and "Model" logic.

I usually prefer to move "selection" state inside the model.
Suppose You have a class "Contact" you use to fill cell data (usual MVC pattern)
I add:

```
class contact{
..
var selected = false
}
```

AND in TV delegation method I use to apply selection, OR better I use a custom selection method in a custom cell (for example to see a √ element in cell)
As a bonus multiple selection come for free, and you can also save current selections for next run :)

Comment: I believe that the selection status does not belong in the data model. You probably don't want that in a data model that is synced to other devices via iCloud that selecting a record on one device leads to selecting the same record on another device.

Comment: A) at the contrary... ALL Apple logic about NSUserDefalut works this way. I DO wanto to t the same UX layout I used on other devices.  B) if not, dot SAVE that attributes in model (easy)

Comment: NSUserDefault has nothing to do with a data model. UX Layout has nothing to do with whether a record was selected. My statement was simply that you should think very carefully about storing the selection status in the data model. As long as you only work on one device, it probably doesn't matter, but you should still not see this as a general recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

TableViewCells are reused as soon as they leave the visible area.
This means that a cell whose background you have colored will be deleted from the view hierarchy as soon as it is scrolled up or down. If the corresponding row is scrolled in again, the function `cellForRowAt` is called again for this IndexPath and the cell gets a white background.

The easiest is to save the IndexPaths of the selected cells and check in the `cellForRowAt` function if the current cell has to be selected.

Add the following var to the viewController class:

```swift
var selectedIndexPaths = Set<IndexPath>()
```

and modify the tableView delegate methods:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TasksTableViewCell") as! TasksTableViewCell

    cell.backView.backgroundColor = (selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) ? UIColor(named: "primaryViewColor") : .white)
    
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath)
    {
        selectedIndexPaths.remove(indexPath)
    }
    else
    {
        selectedIndexPaths.insert(indexPath)
    }
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

Comment: this is not working once I scroll down it removes the selected cells too

Comment: You're right. It allows just one selected row. I misread your question. I'll modify the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

step 1: create model

```
class DemoModel {
  var isSelected: Bool = false
  var color: UIColor = .While
 }
```

step 2: and in tableview

```
  var listDemo: [DemoModel] = [DemoModel(),...]

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
   "TasksTableViewCell") as! TasksTableViewCell
    var obj = listDemo[indexPath.row]
   cell.backView.backgroundColor = obj.color

   return cell
 } 

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   var obj = listDemo[indexPath.row]
   obj.color = UIColor(named: "primaryViewColor")
   tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```